# add onclick event to template

Tags: javascript, html

I have problem that cannot add event onclick to my element. If I call it like that:

```
<td onclick="${console.log('bam')}">X</td>
```

Event is called immediately, so I assumed that if I do it like this:

```
<td onclick="${() => console.log('bam')}">X</td>
```

It will work after click but unfortunately with such a code it stops  to work at all. Anyone knows how to fix it? Oh And I wish to achieve it without jQuery. 
Whole code:

```
this.device.error_log.map((el, i) => {
            if (el.message.component == "displays") {
                return (result += `
            <tr error_id="${i}">
             <td>
                ${this.device.error_log[i].message.component}
             </td>
             <td>
                ${this.device.error_log[i].message.info}
             </td>
             <button onclick="${() => console.log('bam)}">
                X
             </button>
            </tr>`);
            }
        });
    this.error_table.innerHTML += result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea would be create the elements *inside* the function, assign event handlers to them, and then append them to the table:

```
this.device.error_log.forEach((el, i) => {
  if (el.message.component == "displays") {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.setAttribute('error_id', i);
    tr.innerHTML = `
             <td>
                ${this.device.error_log[i].message.component}
             </td>
             <td>
                ${this.device.error_log[i].message.info}
             </td>
             <button>
                X
             </button>`;
    tr.querySelector('button').onclick = () => this.bam();
    this.error_table.appendChild(tr);
  }
});
```

Note that you should only use `.map` when you need to create a new array. Here, you want to perform side effects (alter the DOM), so you should use `.forEach` instead.

While it would be *possible* to change things around to use an inline handler instead, inline handlers are generally considered to be quite poor practice - they lead to fragile code, require global pollution, have string escaping issues, have scoping problems, and have a weird `with` mechanism, among other things. Better to attach the listener explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can do this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onClick="javascript: console.log('test')">test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

or like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onclick=`${console.log('test')}`>test</td> <!––  Notice the backtick -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

or, even simplier:

```html
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td onClick="console.log('test')">test</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: can you explain why use `"javascript: console.log('test')"` ?. simple `onClick="console.log('test')"` also work as same

Comment: I'm listing all the way similar to OP question, _javascript: console.log()_  works too, so I have to list it.